# Admob always return error ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL error code 3

Tags: android, admob

We use advertise in our application, before few days app 
was rejected due to Google Permission Policy change for CALL_LOG and SMS, 
after that we uploaded it again by removing CALL_LOG and SMS permissions 
but now advertisement is stopped and give this error "failed to load ad : 
3". Same ad unit ids are working fine with app demo which is provided by 
admob. We found that some changes in admob policy, for that we updated 
privacy policy URL on play store as well as application. After this changed 
we re-uploaded app but result is the same.

Please help me to resolved this issue.

Comment: You app package name have been blocked by Admob so ,you need change package name of app.

Comment: @Gautam Kushwaha I can't change app package name because thousands of user are there so please suggest me alternative solution.

Comment: I think ,you need to contact with 'admob' regarding this issue. check your email and search 'admob' regarding email and find contact details. You got already an email from 'admob' regarding package name.

Comment: @Gautam Kushwaha No, there is no any email from admob related to ad or package name.